# converting duplicate terms in JSON String to an Array

Tags: java, json

My requirement is to convert a repeating term in to array in json string.

```
    {  
   "ExtendedData":{  
      "OrderRecord":{  
         "ABC_OrderRG":{  
            "ABC_OrderRGLvl1":{  
               "ABC_OrderRGLvl1String":"A"
            },
            "ABC_OrderRGLvl1":{  
               "ABC_OrderRGLvl1String":"B",

            },
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I would like to convert the repeated  term `"ABC_OrderRGLvl1"` to an array some thing like this.

```
 {            
   "ExtendedData":{  
      "OrderRecord":{  
         "ABC_OrderRG":{  
            "ABC_OrderRGLvl1":[  
               {  
                  "ABC_OrderRGLvl1String":"A"
               },
               {  
                  "ABC_OrderRGLvl1String":"B",

               }
            ]
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I have been using org.json.JSONObject which fail anyway at putOnce with duplicate Key error.

The solution I can think of is writing my own parser . Is there any better suggestions or any existing utility for this ?

Comment: I wonder if using gson stream parsing would help?  I'm not familiar, but it seems you'd need something that would read one of the ABC_OrderRGLvl1 values without reading the next and stomping on it.

Comment: @billjamesdev You are right gson stream is better. As of now I am using JSONTokenizer for tokenizing but gson seems to better.  Using stack we can solve the read next problem

Answer (score 0):

To start with the results of parsing such JSON can be unpredictable as per
[RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159#section-4)
Which says

> When the names within an object are not unique, the behavior of software that receives such an object is unpredictable

One way of doing it is by using Jackson Streaming API. Instantiate jsonparser and read the json token by token and write you own logic to handle duplicate keys
http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes

Comment: Thanks Tyagi I am using org.json.JSONTokener.java which is pretty good in tokenizing. I am almost done with my parsing now.